# Displaying button in the Grid view at particular condition

Tags: jquery, gridview

I need to show my data in the Grid view in the exact format as attached in the image. I have every thing in place except the Insert button. This button will appear at the last row of the same Focus Area i.e. if i have two rows with the Focus Area "Client" then the Insert Row button will appear at the second row and not at all the rows. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qM8Q.png)

Any help will highly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdMBO" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdMBO_RowDataBound"
                OnRowCommand="grdMBO_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="ID">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMBOID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MBOToolID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Performance Focus Area">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFocusArea" Text='<%# Eval("PerformanceFocusArea") %>' Visible="false"
                                runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpFocusArea" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Client"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Commercial Management"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Ideas"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="People"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Specific and Unique Capabilities"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="In Year or Multi Year">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblYearSelected" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SelectedYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radGoals" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="In Year" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Multi Year" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Goal**">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("AnnualGoal") %>'
                                Rows="5" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Goal Team" HeaderStyle-Width="500px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 45%" valign="top">
                                        <i>Please enter name & wait for Auto-Suggestion</i>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Width="80%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoComp" runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength="2" TargetControlID="txtName"
                                            ServiceMethod="GetNames" CompletionListCssClass="AjaxRecordDisplay" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AjaxHighlightRecord"
                                            CompletionListItemCssClass="AjaxItemDisplay" Enabled="true" ServicePath="WebService.asmx">
                                        </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 10%">
                                        <%--  <input type="button" id="btnSelectName" runat="server"  value=">>" />--%>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnSelectName" runat="server" Text=">>" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 45%">
                                        <asp:ListBox ID="lstSelectedName" Width="80%" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedName" runat="server" />
                                        <i>(Double click to remove name)</i>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TT Feedback">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTTComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgAdd" runat="server" Width="20px" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.ID") %>'
                                CommandName="Add" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Layout/Images/Add.jpg" />&nbsp;
                            <%-- <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Layout/Images/Delete.jpg" />--%>
                            <img src="~/Layout/Images/Delete.jpg" id="imgDelete" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;
                                cursor: pointer" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: need some code to answer this

Comment: here is my gridview code:-